# What is the proper word for a failure which can not recover by retry?

Tags: word-choice

I developed a web application.

When users call my application, my application may failed and it will returns `FAIL`.

Some users will retry when they received `FAIL`.

Sometimes it works, but in some cases, my application knows the retry won't recover from that failure. So I want to it returns a new state to indicate a failure which can't recover from retries.

So which is the proper word for that case?

---

By the way, my application will returns [`INIT`,`DOING`,`SUCC`,`FAIL`], and means:

- INIT: app is initializing
- DOING: app is working for user's request
- SUCC: user's request done successfully
- FAIL: user's request failed

Comment: I'd just say it's an unrecoverable failure, personally.

Comment: How about `UNAVAILABLE `? It means my app is not available for your request. @JohnClifford

Comment: The problem there is that people might think that's just temporary unavailability and retry anyway. Specifying "unrecoverable" makes it clear that trying again won't work.

Comment: @JohnClifford Really thanks and I will use `unrecoverable`.

Comment: @JohnClifford My merge request was rejected and we decide to use `UNABLE`... Because `unrecoverable ` is too long for other developers...

Comment: That should hopefully still get the point across; didn't consider length, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corresponding value issued from the logging system commonly used in the Java world  is **FATAL**.
If the **FATAL** status occurs, you'll know for sure that the application won't recover from this final state..

Comment: Thanks your advice, but I think it's hard to let an ordinary user have a sense that `FATAL` means unrecoverable ...

Comment: You think people don't know what a fatality is? Maybe you I right, it's difficult to guess

Comment: My web application is for Chinese users which English may be very poor..